# Json Parsing in Java Get the Values from array by Provding Keys only one Time?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

For example,
The following JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }
]
```

---

How can we get the keys only once when we dealing with large number of arrays .like Give id it give the keys of all arrays again and again. I just want to get id only once and when user enter id it gives values of id in whole array.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ValueNode;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file=new File("src/data.json");
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        try {

            LinkedHashMap<String,String> map= new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            JsonNode node =mapper.readTree(file);
            getKeys("",node, map);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() );
            }
            System.out.println();
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(map.get(scanner.next()));

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void getKeys(String currentpath,JsonNode node,LinkedHashMap map){
        if(node.isObject()){
            ObjectNode objectNode=(ObjectNode) node;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it=objectNode.fields();
            String prefix=currentpath.isEmpty()?"":currentpath+".";
            while (it.hasNext()){
                SortedMap.Entry<String,JsonNode> iter=it.next();
                getKeys(prefix+iter.getKey(),iter.getValue(),map);
            }
        }else if (node.isArray()){
            ArrayNode arrayNode=(ArrayNode) node;
            for(int i=0; i<arrayNode.size(); i++){
                getKeys(currentpath+i,arrayNode.get(i),map);
            }
        }
        else if(node.isValueNode()) {
            ValueNode valueNode=(ValueNode) node;
            map.put(currentpath,valueNode.asText());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Below is code outcome and expected outcome

```
key:0.address.city
Key:0.address.geo.lng
Key:0.name
Key:0.username

key:1.address.city
Key:1.address.geo.lng
Key:1.name
Key:1.username

output should like this with out index of array

name
username
address.city
address.geo.lng

 Graham
 Bret
 Gwenborough
 81.1496

 aham
 ret
 borough
 80.1496

------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Map<String, List<String>>` in order to map a key to all its values. E.g. replace

```
else if (node.isValueNode()) {
...
}
```

with

```
else if (node.isValueNode()) {
    ValueNode valueNode = (ValueNode) node;
    final List<String> values = map.getOrDefault(currentpath, new ArrayList<>());
    values.add(valueNode.asText());
    map.put(currentpath, values);
}
```

If you now enter the id, it will show all values in a list.

Comment: kreutez it,s just getting unique key,s and when we enter key it,s not give all values of the key  the particuar key.

Comment: getting keys is simple we can only return the index of the first array to get keys  but issue is  with values, we need to provide key only once and get all the values

Comment: ahh.. I think that now I understand what you are after. Let me see.

Comment: @saqibriaz I edited my answer. Can you check if this works for you?

Comment: Yeah it,s close to what i want.

Comment: @Michal kreutez it,s getting values in array list, can we more simplify during printing result .1,2,3 on different line with out array surronding it.

Comment: Yes, instead of printing the list in `System.out.println(map.get(scanner.next()));` you iterate over the elements of the list and print each element separately.

Comment: @Thanks very much ,it,s working accordingly what i was expecting.